# How do you specify number format on a bar graph in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

In chart expert, Number Format is greyed out unless you explicitly set a min and max value for the chart. I have no idea why those two options are coupled together and it makes NO sense at all. Is there any way I can have my values represented as currency without picking arbitrary min/max values for the data ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just looking in the wrong place. Click on one of your axis labels (the numeric axis you want to change) and then right-click it and select "Format Axis Label". If you look under the "Number" tab, you can change the "Category" to currency and format it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another method if you want even more control is to use a formula..

- totext({tablename.fieldname}, 0) + "%"
- "£" + totext({tablename.fieldname}, 0)

Etc. These will give you full control over the appearance of your data. (note you should use this for grouping fields [ie week number], not for quantity fields [ie sales]).